# How to update an entire object using jdbcTemplate without specifying column names?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I was looking at the reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). We can do this -

`String orderSql = "select * from order where id = ?";
jdbcTemplate.query(orderSql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Order.class), orderId);`

This reads from the database and can directly deserialise into the `Order` object. This is well and good.

What I want to do is -

`String updateSql = "update order ? where id = ?";
jdbcTemplate.save(updateSql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Order.class), order, orderId);`

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you write a method to build the query first based on the column information and return that query to use in the jdbcTemplate.update(...) method.

Comment: That is a way but wouldn't it be more convenient to just pass in an object and let it decide which columns have changed and update the corresponding?

Comment: you are not passing object, and if you wish so i recommend to use hibernate it knows the state of object.

Comment: That is called JPA... Spring has now way of knowing what columns to persist. The row mapper is a best effort and only works if the names match exactly. If you want to do updates like that, use JPA instead.

Comment: I've used JPA before which works this way. For some reason we decided to use raw queries with jdbctemplate. Hence the question!

Comment: With that decision also comes the fact that you will have to manually write your insert/update queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `JdbcTemplate` comes with the ability to map an object using `query` as you've said without having to define columns/attributes, but there is no equivalent usage for `update`. You will have to pass in your SQL and the relevant parameters. As someone has mentioned if you *really* want to do this you could consider using hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query for update  :-

```
String updateSql = "update <table_name> set order= ? where id = ?";

jdbcTemplate.update(updateSql, new Object[]{order, orderId});
```

It will return affected row update count.

Answer (score 0):

No ! You can only do this !

```
jdbcTemplate.update("update ordertable set order = ? where id = ?", order, orderId);
```